# Error of derivatives of polynomial interpolant and best nodes with lobatto constraint

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, interpolation

I know when interpolating a function $f(x)$ by a degree $n$ polynomial $P(x)$, the error is

$$f(x) - P(x) = \frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$$

What does the right side hand look like for the error of the derivatives?

$$f^{(n)}(x) - P^{(n)}(x) = \text{???}$$

Also the product factor is minimized by the Chebyshev nodes. How about when the points $x_0 = -1$ and $x_n = 1$ are added as constrains? I found the first ones:

$$\{-1, 1\}\quad\{-1, 0, 1\}\quad\left\{-1,1-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}-1,1\right\}\\\left\{-1,\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)/2,0,\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)/2,1\right\}\\\left\{-1,-\sqrt{2 \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)},-\sqrt{7-4 \sqrt{3}},\sqrt{7-4 \sqrt{3}},\sqrt{4-2 \sqrt{3}},1\right\}$$

But I fail to see a pattern. Is there any references?

Comment: You can simplify the last line: $4-2\sqrt3=(\sqrt3-1)^2$ and $7-4\sqrt3=(2-\sqrt3)^2$.

Comment: I realized now that the product factor minimization must be simply a scaling of the chebychev nodes by the largest root of the n'th chebyshev polynomial